# Text not displaying correctly

Tags: macos, font

We just recently got new iMacs at work, and we're all having the same issue

[image: Screenshot]

Not only do we get characters like those in all web browsers, but even some apps!

Is there a way to fix the characters? We've tried changing default fonts without success :(

I'm running 10.9.2

The problem happens in local apps as well, not just browsers. How can I check fonts integrity?

Comment: Try a safe boot  http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14204  Have you added any non-Apple font to these machines?  It looks like a junk version of the Last Resort Font substituting for Latin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Applications folder, there is an app called Font Book.

Open this app and go to File → Restore Standard System Fonts. This will remove any non-standard fonts on your system and reinstall any missing standard fonts.

Answer (score -2):

Go to font book and disable Helvetica font family